# about the role of protected access modifier

Tags: java, inheritance

i have a base class A and derived class B, A contains a protected memeber, is it possible to access this member and change its value directly through a refrence type of the derived class B.
given this definitions:

```
class A {

 protected int xMember = 45;

 public int getXMember() {
   return xMember;
 }

}

class B extends A { }
```

is this code correct:

```
B b = new B();
b.xMember = 100;
```

Comment: What did the compiler tell you?

Comment: `class B` *inherits* the `protected` member from `class A`, which means it as good as if defined in `class B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b.xMember = 100;` would pass compilation only if this code is located in a class that belongs to the same package as `A` or extends `A`.